# Capistrano Multistage deploying to wrong directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Im having some problems with my capistrano setup after updating my gems lately. I have a multistage setup with a production and staging setup.

/config/deploy.rb

```
# setup multistage
set :stages, %w(testing production)
set :default_stage, "testing"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
```

/config/deploy/production.rb

```
# Set deploy path
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/mysite/live"
set :rails_env, "production"
```

/config/deploy/testing.rb

```
# Set deploy path
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/mysite/test"
set :rails_env, "test"
```

Problem is that it seems to ignore my deploy_to setting. It just deploys to the default /u/apps/mysite.

I don't know if it has any relevance, the cause of all of this is a move from apache+passenger to nginx+unicorn. I don't think it has anything to do with that though, as this is just the checkout process.

Comment: There has to be a way to do this without duplicating the config across every single stage. Ideas?

Comment: Answer your question with the solution and accept it, so it will show as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by adding the following to my deploy/production.rb and testing.rb

```
set(:deploy_to)         { "/var/www/#{application}/live" }
set(:releases_path)     { File.join(deploy_to, version_dir) }
set(:shared_path)       { File.join(deploy_to, shared_dir) }
set(:current_path)      { File.join(deploy_to, current_dir) }
set(:release_path)      { File.join(releases_path, release_name) }
```

Answer (score 9):

I stumbled across this while on Stack Overflow. Its an old question but since its flagged as open I'm going to give it a shot.

I think this might be a scope issue with how the Capistrano Instances get loaded.

I notice this syntax doesn't work in the production.rb and test.rb files

```
 set :deploy_to, "/var/www/mysite/live"
```

But this one does:

```
set(:deploy_to)  { "/var/www/#{application}/live" }
```

Its a subtle difference but I think the one that works is actually passing the information as a Proc block, whereas the first one is passing it as a string. I have a sneaky suspicion that by the time the Capistrano Instance comes into being that string is no longer present.

This would indicate to me that something is off in your load or require order as you should be able to set the deploy variables in these files. If you can't figure it out you may be able to *cheat* and surround the *deploy/production.rb* or *deploy/test.rb* code with

```
Capistrano::Configuration.instance.load do
  # variables, etc here
end
```

That would definitely tell you that this file isn't being loaded within the scope of the Capistrano instance.

Also minor point but the files should be in

```
config/deploy # relative to your Rails app
```

Not

```
/config/deploy/ # this is an absolute path off of your root folder
```

Good Luck. Hopefully you've already solved this issue!

Comment: The `set(:deploy_to)  { "/var/www/#{application}/live" }` does not work with capistrano 3.x. I get the following message `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`

Comment: Cap 3 is a complete API rewrite IIRC, they're trying to clean up the legacy code base. This syntax will def work in 2 though... :)

Answer (score 0):

Where are those production.rb and testing.rb located in the project?

Make sure they are under `config/deploy`.

Comment: Yes, they are in /config/deploy/production.rb & testing.rb

Comment: try requiring require 'capistrano/ext/multistage' before setting the stages

Comment: I'd try also using set :deploy_to, "/mypath/#{stage}" in the main deploy.rb

Comment: `method_missing_with_variables': undefined local variable or method `stage'. I also tried adding set :stage, 'production' in the production.rb to see if that worked

Answer (score -4):

Could be just the order you have it in your **deploy.rb**? put the require above the stage settings

```
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

# setup multistage
set :stages, %w(testing production)
set :default_stage, "testing"
```

Comment: As explained in the official [wiki page](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension) for the multistage extension, the `require` **must** come after the two `set`.