# Symfony2 Capifony deployment - Conflicts on a same server

Tags: deployment, symfony, apc, capifony

I want to deploy different branchs of a Git repository on a same server.

I've updated app/config/deploy.rb

```
set :stage_dir, "app/config/deploy"
require "capistrano/ext/multistage"
set :stages, %w(prod stag stag2 stag3)
set :application, "MyApp"
```

I've created new files in app/config/deploy/

In app/config/deploy/stag.rb :

```
set :symfony_env_prod, "stag"
set :domain,           "stag.example.com"
set :deploy_to,        "/var/www/#{domain}"

# Other config
role :web,             domain
role :app,             domain
role :db,              domain, :primary => true
```

In app/config/deploy/stag2.rb

```
set :symfony_env_prod, "stag"
set :domain,           "stag2.example.com"
set :deploy_to,        "/var/www/#{domain}"

# Other config
role :web,             domain
role :app,             domain
role :db,              domain, :primary => true
```

I also launched `cap stag2 deploy:setup`.

When I deploy using `cap stag deploy`, stag.example.com is fine

Then, when I deploy `cap stag2 deploy`,stag2.example.com is file but stag.example.com get some changes from stag2. The source files of stag.example.com are correct. I suppose that there is a cache conflict.

Is Capifony able to deploy the same app in a same server properly ?

Edit : sounds similar [Capistrano Multistage deploying to wrong directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213376/capistrano-multistage-deploying-to-wrong-directory)

I also tried with `set :deploy_to,        "/var/www/stag2/#{domain}"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `server` parameters instead of `:domain`.

`stag.rb`:

```
server "stag.example.com", :app, :web, :primary => true
```

`stag2.rb`:

```
server "stag2.example.com", :app, :web, :primary => true
```

Don't use `:domain` for this stuff.

[See the docs](http://capifony.org/cookbook/using-the-multistage-extension.html).

Answer (score 0):

I tried your solution @Elnur , replacing *server* by *domain*, deployment works fine but the problem still occurs...
After more investigation and tests I came up with a solution that seems to work.

I noticed that in app/autoload.php we use APC

```
$loader = new ApcUniversalClassLoader('xx.');
```

**xx.** is the **A prefix to create a namespace in APC**
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/class_loader.html

I replaced by

```
$loader = new ApcUniversalClassLoader('xx.stagX');
```

Then *restart Apache* and *rm -Rf app/cache/**

That seems to solve the problem. I would be surprised if the same APC name space could be used by 2 different websites on the same server.

This is the exception stack-trace that we got before, look how we go
from /var/www/**stag5**.XXXX.com/
to     /var/www/**stag6**.XXXX.com/

```
#10 /var/www/stag6.XXXX.com/shared/vendor/cg-library/src/CG/Proxy/MethodInvocation.php(58): JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Security\Authorization\Interception\MethodSecurityInterceptor->intercept(Object(CG\Proxy\MethodInvocation))
#11 /var/www/stag5.XXXX.com/releases/20121210053804/app/cache/stag/jms_aop/proxies/St-XxBundle-Manager-XxxManager.php(85): CG\Proxy\MethodInvocation->proceed()
#12 /var/www/stag6.XXXX.com/releases/20121210060841/src/Xx/XxxBundle/Controller/XxxController.php(85): EnhancedProxy_16c750f17d8113ffbee7fc3acdc4b1625ca7410b\__CG__\St\CoreBundle\Manager\TagsManager->findXxxxx(Object(Xx\XxBundle\Entity\Project))
#13 [internal function]: Xx\XxxxxBundle\Controller\XxxxController->getXxxAction(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#14 /var/www/stag5.XXXX.com/releases/20121210053804/app/cache/stag/classes.php(4591): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /var/www/stag5.XXXX.com/releases/20121210053804/app/cache/stag/classes.php(4555): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#16 /var/www/stag5.XXXX.com/releases/20121210053804/app/cache/stag/classes.php(5537): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#17 /var/www/stag5.XXXX.com/releases/20121210053804/app/bootstrap.php.cache(564): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#18 /var/www/stag5.XXXX.com/releases/20121210053804/web/app_stag.php(13): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#19 {main}
```