# capistrano deploy_to does not work when set in a stage config file

Tags: capistrano

I place the `set :deploy_to` in each of the stage config files: `config/deploy/production.rb` and `config/deploy/staging.rb`

Example:

```
set :deploy_to, '/home/user/htdocs/app-name'
```

After running `cap staging deploy:check --trace` I can see that this value was not applied:

```
...
** Execute deploy:check:directories
 INFO [91f6713c] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/shared /var/www/releases on example.net
DEBUG [91f6713c] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -pv /var/www/shared /var/www/releases
...
```

I use a basic capistrano structure:

```
├── Capfile
├── config
│   ├── deploy
│   │   ├── production.rb
│   │   └── staging.rb
│   └── deploy.rb
└── lib
    └── capistrano
            └── tasks
```

I thought that those stage config files are there to define custom variables for each stage?
Which variables can I set in the stage config files?

EDIT:

I'm using capistrano v3

Comment: I think there is already an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213376/capistrano-multistage-deploying-to-wrong-directory), hope it helps.

Comment: @McGar unfortunately this is not the solution. I'm using capistrano v3.

Comment: I just encountered the same situtation. Did you manage to get around this meanwhile?

Comment: I know this question is old, but it would be good to get an answer in here. So, can you show what is in your staging.rb? I believe I know what was causing this.

Answer (score 1):

this seems old, but for my case, i was using capistrano3-puma gem.

i realize ive set my puma config in deploy.rb, but my deploy_to is set in staging.rb and production.rb.

adding puma deploy config in staging.rb after deploy_to works!

eg:

```
set :deploy_to, "/home/username/rails-stg"
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/puma.rb"
set :puma_default_control_app, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/pumactl.sock"
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_bind, %w(tcp://127.0.0.1:3065)
```

Comment: An alternative to setting puma_conf in each environmnent deploy file is to defer evaluation in deploy.rb as per https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/1413#issuecomment-87778255.

`set :puma_conf, -> { "#{shared_path}/puma.rb" }`